# Multiway tree construction from a node string

Tags: algorithm, prolog, multiway-tree

There is a wonderful problem set called Ninety-Nine [Prolog Problems](https://prof.ti.bfh.ch/hew1/informatik3/prolog/p-99/). Problem P70 is the one referred to in the title. And here is a great Prolog [solution](https://prof.ti.bfh.ch/hew1/informatik3/prolog/p-99/p70.pl) of this problem which takes only 5 lines. However, my understanding of Prolog is limited.

How does this solution look like in a C-like form (no itertools available)?

Edited by request. I hope I do not violate copyright.

The problem:

Syntax in BNF:

```
tree ::= letter forest '^'
forest ::= | tree forest
```

A nice solution using difference lists:

```
tree(TS,T) :- atom(TS), !, atom_chars(TS,TL), tree_d(TL-[ ],T). % (+,?)
tree(TS,T) :- nonvar(T), tree_d(TL-[ ],T), atom_chars(TS,TL).   % (?,+)
tree_d([X|F1]-T, t(X,F)) :- forest_d(F1-['^'|T],F).
forest_d(F-F,[ ]).
forest_d(F1-F3,[T|F]) :- tree_d(F1-F2,T), forest_d(F2-F3,F).
```

Comment: You could help us out by actually copying the problem definition etc here. Bring content to stackoverflow whenever practical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem Definition

<sub>(taken from [P-99: Ninety-Nine Prolog Problems](https://web.archive.org/web/20160409014329/https://prof.ti.bfh.ch/hew1/informatik3/prolog/p-99/))</sub>

We suppose that the nodes of a multiway tree contain single characters. In the depth-first order sequence of its nodes, a special character `^` has been inserted whenever, during the tree traversal, the move is a backtrack to the previous level.

By this rule, the tree in the figure is represented as: `afg^^c^bd^e^^^`

[image]
<sub>(source: [ti.bfh.ch](https://prof.ti.bfh.ch/hew1/informatik3/prolog/p-99/p70.gif))</sub>

Define the syntax of the string and write a predicate `tree(String,Tree)` to construct the `Tree` when the `String` is given. Work with atoms (instead of strings). Make your predicate work in both directions.

---

#### Solution Part 1: `String2Tree`

This is easy with a stack. Here's the pseudocode:

```
FUNCTION String2Tree(String str) : Tree
   LET st BE New-Stack<Node>
   LET root BE New-Node
   st.push(root)

   FOREACH el IN str
      IF el IS '^'
         st.pop()
      ELSE
         LET child BE New-Node(el)
         LET top BE st.top()
         top.adopt(child)
         st.push(child)

   RETURN New-Tree(root)
```

The use of a dummy `root` node simplifies matters. Essentially the algorithm is as follows:

- Scan the string left to right
- Whenever we encounter a node label, we create a new node

  - That node is adopted by the top of the stack
  - That node is then pushed to the the stack and becomes the new top
- When we encounter a `'^'`, we simply pop off the top of the stack

---

#### Solution Part 2: `Tree2String`

The opposite direction is a matter of simple recursion:

```
FUNCTION string(Tree t) : String
   LET sb BE New-StringBuffer

   visit(t.root, sb)

   RETURN New-String(sb)

PROCEDURE visit(Node n, StringBuffer sb)
   sb.append(n.label)

   FOREACH child IN n.children()
      visit(child, sb)

   sb.append('^')
```

As specified in the problem, we insert `^` whenever we backtrack to the previous level.

Comment: This is a very nice solution. Thank you polygenelubricants! Typo: 'Tree2String' missing. What happens in 'visit' if the child has no children?

Comment: @John: yes, `FUNCTION string` should be `FUNCTION Tree2String`. When there are no children then `FOREACH` will be a no-op loop, which is exactly what we want. I'll add this correction/clarification with next revision, along with other things I might add.